# Creating a page obgect model using Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following simplified version of the SW stack that is running on the glasses that help to overcome a limitation of a blind person.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTyIn.png)

Scenario: The user walks on the sidewalk and there is a pillar in front at 3-4 meters that needs to be avoided.

The software components themselves run in Python3 on Ubuntu 20.04. Each sub-system has its own development lifecycle, and all sub-systems are integrated in a Software Release. The glasses offer feedback and guidance to the user, who relies on it to be safe at all times. Some features of the system cannot fail without the user knowing.

Python, create a Page Object Model style class called glasses. Populate it with methods and attributes relevant towards testing the functionality of the glasses. Write a script to automate the test cases you have selected for automation. Use the GlassesPage you have just created

```
class LumenGlassesPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.camera_connection = None
        self.imu_connection = None
    
    def connect_to_camera(self, serial_no):
        self.camera_connection = Connection(serial_no)
        return self.camera_connection
    
    def read_rgb_frame(self):
        if self.camera_connection is None:
            raise Exception("Camera not connected")
        return self.camera_connection.read_rgb()
    
    def read_depth_frame(self):
        if self.camera_connection is None:
            raise Exception("Camera not connected")
        return self.camera_connection.read_depth()
    
    def connect_to_imu(self, port):
        self.imu_connection = Connection(port)
        return self.imu_connection
    
    def read_orientation(self):
        if self.imu_connection is None:
            raise Exception("IMU not connected")
        return self.imu_connection.read_orientation()
    
    def perform_object_detection(self, image, model):
        return object_detection.inference(image, model)
    
    def perform_semantic_segmentation(self, image, model):
        return semantic_segmentation.inference(image, model)
    
    def convert_2d_to_3d(self, image):
    
    def process_pointcloud(self, pointcloud):
    
    def convert_pointcloud_to_navigation_map(self, pointcloud):
```

How do I automate the test cases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.